# git checkout and git pull doesn't download files

Tags: git

I've `git pull`ed from a remote repository, and I think it worked, but at one point I deleted a couple of files and now I want them back. The thing is, I have a feeling git thinks they're already there, because it gives a list of files with 'D' on the right of them. these are the files I need to download, but they're just not there in the folder!

How can I simply download all the files? On bit bucket, it lists all the files perfectly. I just want to download these files.

Answer (score 3):

The files should still be in your local copy of the repo. Git pull isn't going to get them for you because you still have them.

Assuming you committed their deletion, "git checkout" those files from an earlier version of the repo.

However, since you say it lists them with a 'd' next to them, I assume you haven't, which means you simply need to checkout the deleted files again. For specific files, typing `git checkout -- [filename]` will do that for you. It checks out the specific file from the current index.

If you want to do undo all your changes, you can `$ git reset --hard HEAD`, although that will also get rid of any other changes you've made in addition to the file deletion.

Comment: I don't think I committed their deletion... What does the D actually mean? And how do I unstage a deletion?

Comment: git checkout is for branches (different from older vcs's), not sure if it's being used in the right context here?

Comment: Git checkout checkouts is used to switch branches as well, yes, but its not the only thing it can do.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: The answer is correct, in fact.  Confusingly, `git checkout` has two different uses - one is to switch HEAD to a particular branch or commit, while the other (if you specify a path) will update that path either from the index or a particular commit.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using `git reset --hard HEAD`, though it solves this specific problem but I can see it messing up if I didn't want an exact copy of the repo...

Answer (score 0):

Just try with git checkout with the tag name or repo sync

Comment: all git checkout does is list all the file names with "D" on the left of them. But when I `ls`, nothing's there!